# How do I write a Bash script to autoadjust the screen resolution of Enlightenment 20 running under VirtualBox?

Tags: shell-script, xrandr, resolution

I have noticed that VirtualBox guest additions fails to autoadjust the screen resolution of Enlightenment 20 on a few different platforms (including Arch Linux, Lubuntu and openSUSE Tumbleweed), see for example [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1584343#p1584343) Arch Linux forum post I wrote and consequently I have been using the script (stored in `~/.bashrc`):

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1366x642
```

to adjust the screen resolution to full screen. The problem is that sometimes the screen height of the mode I want is not 642px, for example I just started up my openSUSE Tumbleweed VM and the screen height of this mode was 671px (making the corrected script for adjusting the screen resolution `xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1366x671`). If the screen height does not match 642px then running `xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1366x642` fails to adjust the screen resolution and returns the error message: `xrandr: cannot find mode 1366x642`. The screen height of this mode can be determined, however, by running `xrandr`, which gives the output in my openSUSE Tumbleweed VM:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 64 x 64, current 800 x 600, maximum 32766 x 32766
VGA-0 connected primary 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm panning 800x600+0+0
   1366x671      60.00 +
   2560x1600     60.00
   2560x1440     60.00
   2048x1536     60.00
   1920x1600     60.00
   1920x1080     60.00
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     60.00
   1400x1050     60.00
   1280x1024     60.00
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.00*
   640x480       60.00
```

I was wondering if it might be possible to filter the output of `xrandr` so as to get the correct value of the screen height which can then be passed to `xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1366x<HEIGHT>`. This is the script I would use (where `$H` is the mode height, as determined by the filter I was hoping for).

```
L=$(xrandr)
H=f($L) # Where f(x) is the filter I am hoping for. 
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1366x$H
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, please indicate with the checkmark so the system knows the question has been answered. If not, please let me know what went wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I no longer run Enlightenment in VMs, and I didn't when you wrote your answer. It's a case of 'You snooze, you lose'. I'd be able to accept it if I still had this problem. To be clear, I'm not attacking you, I realize it'd be naive and narcissistic of me to think everyone in the world is just sitting around, waiting to answer any questions I type, it's just you're too late this time.

Comment: Well, hopefully it's helpful to future readers in the same situation. I'll case a VTC since no one will be able to properly Answer the question.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you could use:

```
H=$(xrandr | awk '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+x[[:digit:]]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$/ && $3 == "+" { print substr($1, index($1, "x")+1) }')
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1366x$H
```

Here's the awk program nicely formatted:

```
'$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+x[[:digit:]]+$/ && \
 $2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$/ && \
 $3 == "+" \ 
 { print substr($1, index($1, "x")+1) }'
```

I started with a simple `$3 == "+"`, which seems to grab the correct line, but I added some paranoia with `$1` and `$2` checking. The `print` line prints a portion of $1: after computing the position of the "x" in the dimensions, skipping one place past it, it prints from there to the end of $1.